# how to connect MySQL database to input function

Tags: python, mysql

I'm building a program, where the user input an enterprise's name to get the code running.

I would like the user to pick the enterprise name in a drop down list, but currently i dont have a GUI to make it work.

so for now, I would like to connect the input function to the SQL database enterprises name column.

I already connected SQL to my python code... but how do I connect MySQL to an input function? I want the user to be able to get the information from the database

**MY SQL CONNECTION :**

```
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", user="nn", passwd="passpass")

mycursor = mydb.cursor()

mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM listedatabase.entreprises_inspecteurs")

for row in mycursor.fetchall():
    print (row[1])

mydb.close()
```

**python:**

```
enterprise_name = input()
```

Thank you for helping

**I tried this but no luck:**

```
 mydb = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", user="nn", passwd="passpass")

    mycursor = mydb.cursor()

    enterprise_name = input()
    mycursor.execute("SELECT n_fabricant FROM listedatabase.entreprises_inspecteurs", (enterprise_name,))
    data = mycursor.fetchall()
    if data:
        code goes there
    else: 
        print('data not found in database')
```

Comment: So where does the `enterprise_name` go?

Comment: Like `SELECT ... WHERE name=?`?

Comment: @SwetankPoddar it linked to google calendar api. Enterprise_name is represented by the `SUMMARY` description of an event.

Comment: @tadman Yes, does it work like that inside a python code?

Comment: Python just passes along the statement you want to run, it doesn't care what's in it.

Comment: @tadman can you take a look at my answer ? What do you think about it?

Comment: You need to add a `WHERE` clause, you can't just attach data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 mydb = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", user="nn", passwd="passpass")

    mycursor = mydb.cursor()

    enterprise_name = input()
    mycursor.execute("""SELECT n_fabricant FROM listedatabase.entreprises_inspecteurs WHERE n_fabricant = %s"""(event_inspecteur,))
    data = mycursor.fetchall()
    if data:
        code goes there
    else: 
        print('data not found in database')
```